# Scala method not being invoked

Tags: scala, implicit

Here I'm attempting to invoke a function with the use of implicit's. To try to remove as much boiler plate code as possible invoking function using :

```
("a" and "j", {
  println("Hello");
})
```

But this does not invoke `f1`

how to invoke the function `f1` with the call

```
("a" and "j", {
  println("Hello");
})
```

?

Complete code :

```
   object First extends App {

      case class Commands(val list: List[String]) {
        def and(that: String) = Commands(that :: list)
      }
      implicit def l(cmd: String) = Commands(cmd :: Nil)

      implicit def f1(implicit d: (Commands, () => Unit)): Unit = {
        val launchCommand = d._1.list.reverse.mkString("") + "::"
        println(launchCommand)

        println("This method is not being invoked");
        d._2()
      }

      ("a" and "j", {
        println("Hello");
      })

    }
```

Update :

```
object First extends App {

  case class Commands(val list: List[String]) {
    def and(that: String) = Commands(that :: list)
  }
  implicit def l(cmd: String) = Commands(cmd :: Nil)

  implicit def f1(implicit d: (Commands, () => Unit)): Unit = {
    val launchCommand = d._1.list.reverse.mkString("") + "::"
    println(launchCommand)

    println("This method is not being invoked");
    d._2()
  }

  implicit val commandAndFunc = ("a" and "j", {
    println("Hello");
  })

  f1
}
```

`f1` causes compiler error :

```
Multiple markers at this line:
◾not enough arguments for method f1: (implicit d: (First.Commands, () ⇒ Unit))Unit. Unspecified value parameter d.
◾could not find implicit value for parameter d: (First.Commands, () ⇒ Unit)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  implicit val commandAndFunc: (Commands, () => Unit) = ("a" and "j", { () =>
    println("Hello")
  })

f1
```

this would invoke f1 with commandAndFunc.
You just define a tuple of a command and a function. Why should it call f1?
How should the compiler/the program know, if it is a call to f1 or just a declaration of a tuple of type `Tuple2[Command,() => Unit]`?
With implicit you can hand over a parameters without writing them explicit or you can convert an object implicit. You can not make the compiler know magically what you want to call.

Comment: Edited it, the type of `commandAndFunc` was wrong, just copied your code

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
 case class Commands(val list: List[String]) {
    def and(that: String) = Commands(that :: list)
  }

  implicit def l(cmd: String) = Commands(cmd :: Nil)

  implicit class f1(d: (Commands, () => Unit)) {

    def exec(): Unit = {
      val launchCommand = d._1.list.reverse.mkString("") + "::"
      println(launchCommand)

      println("This method is not being invoked");
      d._2()
    }
  }

  val b = ("a" and "j", () => println("Hello"))

  b.exec()
```